# Vue.js v-show not working after axios

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, axios

v-show is not working as I expected, I'm guessing it is because *this.conversation.hidden* is not set when browser is rendered since it is coming with async call. In this case, how can I make it work?

Thanks in progress! And tell me if my description is insufficientㅠ

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-show="conversation.hidden">hidden</div>
      <div v-show="!conversation.hidden">not hidden</div>

      <button @click="conversation.hidden = false">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      conversation: {},
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios.get('request_something', {
    }).then((response) => {
      this.conversation = response.data;
      this.conversation.hidden = true;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

---------SOLVED--------------
as @thanksd mentioned in my comment, using Vue.set() will solve this problem. I should have explained more briefly with my question, but he knew what I was looking for. :) Thanks to others who answered me too.

Comment: Vue.js cannot detect property addition/deletions. Use `this.$set(this.conversation, 'hidden', true)` instead. Please see https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

Comment: You might want to consider using v-if / v-else instead of v-show(condition) / v-show(!condition)

Comment: @thanksd Great answer! that's what I was looking for! And also appreciate the link, such a great source. : )

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `hidden` to your `conversation` object it will work. Vue will look for the object and if the object is undefined it won't work.

```
conversation: {
    hidden: false
}
```

take a look at jsFiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/141516/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try conditional rendering:

```html
<template>
  <div v-cloak>
    <div v-if="conversation.hidden">Hidden</div>
    <div v-else>Not Hidden</div>
    <button @click="toggleConversation">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      conversation: {
        data: [], 
        hidden: true 
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get('/endpoint').then((response) => {
      if (response.data) {
        this.conversation.data = response.data
        this.conversation.hidden = false      
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    toggleConversation() {
      this.conversation.hidden = !this.conversation.hidden
    }
  }
}
</script>
```